# html-css floating divs fit container height

Tags: html, css

After a couple of hours searching solutions I'm still stucked. I have a window and a content div and a buttons div inside this window. The content div can have various fixed width groups inside , which are generated by php code.
These groups have various number of lines of content, which means that each group have different height according to the content generated. As the container width is changing by the different media, the content is repositioning the divs inside.

How can I make all the groups' height adjust to fill the remaining height of the content div with css , but maintain the floating div's responsible behavior?

In the examle here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt48c852/1/) there is 3 groups and 3 heights, the goal would be to have all the groups heights adjusted to fit the remaining space, even when the container's width is reduced and the third group is positioned downside of the second group.
The example code so far is:

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="winContent" style="display:table;background-color: lightyellow">
            <div id="dataContent" style="display:table-row;background-color: lightblue">
                    <div id="group1" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;">
                        GROUP1<br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                    </div>
                     <div id="group2" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;">
                         GROUP2<br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="group3" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;">
                        GROUP3<br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                        A few lines of text <br />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="winButtons" class="btnClass" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
                BTN1 BTN2 
            </div>
    </div>
```

```
<style>
.grpClass{width:200px;float:left;  
border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8AC007;padding: 5px;

}
.btnClass{display:table-row;float:right;
border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8AC007;padding: 5px; margin-top:5px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Have a look into using flexbox, it can do exactly what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to remove the float and replace it with `display:table-cell`:

```
.grpClass {
    width:200px;
    display:table-cell;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wt48c852/2/)**

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited the question according to the responsive behavior

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```css
.grpClass{border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8AC007;padding: 5px;
width: 33.3333%;display: table-cell;
}
.btnClass{display:table-row;border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #8AC007;padding: 5px; float:right; margin-top:5px;}
.winContent{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="window">
  <div id="winContent" style="display:table;background-color: lightyellow">
    <div id="dataContent" style="display:table-row;background-color: lightblue">
      <div id="group1" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;"> GROUP1<br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
      </div>
      <div id="group2" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;"> GROUP2<br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
      </div>
      <div id="group3" class="grpClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;"> GROUP3<br />
        A few lines of text <br />
        A few lines of text <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="winButtons" class="btnClass" style="background-color: lightcoral;"> BTN1 BTN2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited the question according to the responsive behavior